# Does $zx^T - x y^T - y z^T \ge 0$ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, inequality, matrix-equations

Suppose $x,y,z$ are three **row** vectors of the same length, and they satisfy :

(1) each element in $x,y,z$ is between 0 and 1

(2) $\|x\|_{\infty} \le 1, \quad \|y\|_{\infty} \le 1, \quad \|z\|_{\infty} \le 1$

(NOTE: $\|x\|_{\infty}$ means the **row** sum of $x$)

(3) each column of the matrix $\left[ \begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{matrix} \right]$ has only two nonzero elements.

My question is: Does this inequality hold?

$zx^T - x y^T - y z^T \ge 0$

Comment: Yes, I have corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a simple counter-example is
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z  \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} a & a & 0 \\ a & 0 & a \\ 0 & a & a  \end{pmatrix}
$$
for any $0 < a \le 1/2$. Each row sum is $2a$ and
$$
zx^T - x y^T - y z^T = a^2 - a^2 - a^2 = -a^2 < 0 \, .
$$

Comment: Sorry, your solution reminds me that I missed one condition (2).

Comment: @JohnSmith: But $\|x\|_{\infty} = \|y\|_{\infty} = \|z\|_{\infty} = 1$ in this example. Or how do you define that norm?

Comment: $x$ is row vector. I mean row sum.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Then take $x = (1/2, 1/2, 0)$ etc.